# MySQL multiple table select with WHERE not comparing 2 tables

Tags: mysql, multiple-select

I have the beginnings of a query:

`SELECT tf_threads.*, tf_posts.* FROM tf_threads, tf_posts WHERE tf_threads.thread_id=54`

Of course, it's just the start of one - I'm moving one step at a time so it will become much better as time passes. What I'm stuck on at the moment, however, is how to get a `WHERE` clause to compare a column in one table with a PHP variable, not another column.

The PHP I have is this:

`SELECT $tf_threads.*, $tf_posts.* FROM $tf_threads, $tf_posts WHERE $tf_threads.thread_id=$tf_this_forum`

The important bit here is `$tf_threads.thread_id=$tf_this_forum`. When I try this it simply returns no rows, with MySQL saying: `Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables`. Surely this should work fine? Obviously, it doesn't, so can anyone help out here please?

Thanks very much,

James

**EDIT:** I have also tried doing the query in pure MySQL like this:

`SELECT tf_threads.*, tf_posts.* FROM tf_threads, tf_posts WHERE tf_threads.thread_id=54`

Both WITH quotes round the `54` and without, with the same no rows result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is implicitly performing a CROSS JOIN and it appears to contain too many `$` signs.

I'd suggest the following extra changes:

- Use ANSI-92 joins (the JOIN keyword) instead of ANSI-89 joins (the comma).
- Use [`intval`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) applied to $tf_this_forum to ensure that it is an integer.
- Consider using bind parameters instead of constructing the query from strings dynamically.
- Only use `$` when you are referring to a PHP variable.

Regarding the error *Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables* this means that no rows matched. Check that the row you are searching for actually exists in your database. It could be that it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! Your `JOIN` bullet point worked great; doing this query works perfectly: `SELECT tf_threads.*, tf_posts.* FROM tf_threads LEFT JOIN tf_posts ON tf_threads.thread_id=54`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tf_threads.*, tf_posts.* FROM tf_threads, tf_posts WHERE
tf_threads.thread_id='$tf_this_forum'
```

Note: You should [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) `$tf_this_forum` if it hasn't yet been escaped.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but `thread_id` is a numerical field anyway - I should have included that in my OP to avoid confusion. Please see @Mark Byer's post for the solution :-)

Comment: Also, +1 for the good advice to other users - you can't always guarantee a variable will be numeric!